# Haskell: Non-exhaustive patterns in function (simple functions)

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I am confused as to why the 1st and 3rd versions of this functions give this error whereas the second definition works fine.

```
-- head and tail
third :: [a] -> a
third [a] = head (tail (tail[a]))

-- Pattern matching
third2 :: [a] -> a
third2 (_:_:x:_) = x

-- List indexing
third3 :: [a] -> a
third3 [a] = [a]!!2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ghc 7.4.1 with `-Wall` complains about all three functions.  What compiler do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is odd that the second one does not complain about non-exhaustive
patterns, since `third2` will not match lists of length zero, one, or two.
The `third` and `third3` functions complain because `[a]` is not a variable,
it is a pattern. `[a]` desugars to `(a:[])`, so you could have written them as

```
third (a:[]) = head (tail (a:[]))

third3 (a:[]) = (a:[]) !! 2
```

Neither of which will work, as those are single element lists.
I suspect what you want is

```
third a = head (tail a)

third3 a = a !! 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the syntax better.

Basically, there are 2 sub-syntaxes:

1. syntax for types
2. syntax for expressions and patterns

In the type syntax, `[a]` means `list of elements of type a`

In the expression/pattern syntax, `[a]` means the singleton list, that contains the value `a`. This is equivalent to `(a:[])`  (a prepended to the empty list).

Hence your first function, for example, checks if it gets a singleton list. Then it takes the head of the tail of the tail of a singleton list, which will fail.

The message you're getting is because there are shapes of lists you didn't cover: namely, the empty list and lists with more than 1 element.

And, of course, you should be getting a warning for `third2`, is it only covers lists with 3 or more elements. I am sure you're overlooking something.

Comment: The question appears to be about why doesn't the second function raise such error, not what this error means.

Comment: I do not believe it doesn't.