# Haskell Data Declaration : Find sum of Leaves in a binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, non-exhaustive-patterns

Here is a binary tree, and i am trying to calculate the sum of the leaves

```
             -1
            /   \
          -5     10
          / \   
        -4  30  
        / \
       13  17
```

The data declaration is given.

```
data Tree = TNode Int [ Tree ] | TLeaf Int
```

and here is my code

```
let t = TNode (-1) [TNode (-5)  [  TNode (-4) [ Tleaf 13, Tleaf 17] ,  Tleaf 30 ] ,Tleaf 10 ]

sumLeaves (Tleaf x)= x
sumLeaves (TNode x [tree])=  sum[sumLeaves tree]
```

When i run the program sumLeaves t,it shows that there is  non-exhaustive patterns in the function sumLeaves.I think the  problem is the programm can't count,when there is a node with two leaves,but i don't know how to solve it.A little help is really appreciated.

Edited :
test1:

```
 sumLeaves1 (Tleaf x)= [x]
    sumLeaves1 (TNode x [Tleaf y])=[y]
    sumLeaves1 (TNode x (y:ys))= sum ( (sumLeaves1 y) ++ (sumLeaves1 (TNode x ys)) )
```

test 2:

```
 sumLeaves (Tleaf x)= x
    sumLeaves (TNode x [Tleaf y])=y
    sumLeaves (TNode x (y:ys))= (sumLeaves y) + sumLeaves (TNode x ys)
```

test 2 works fine,but test 1 gives error, when i remove the sum(),it gives a list [13,17,30,10] ,which is the correct list, but  >sum ( [13,17,30,10]) works in programm.How can i overcome it?

Comment: the answer you are looking for is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897649/849891) in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(Tnode x [tree])` only matches if the node has *exactly* one subtree. You should match any value of sublistlist, so:

```
sumLeaves :: Tree -> Int
sumLeaves (Tleaf x) = x
sumLeaves (TNode x trees) = sum (…)
```

here the `…` should create a list of the sums of the children of the node. You thus should make a mapping for each element in `trees`. I leave this as an exercise. You might want to look at [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map).

That being said, you do not have to sum the elements yourself. You can lift the `Tree` data type and make use of the [**`DeriveFoldable`** extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable) to let Haskell derive a `Foldable` instance for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = TNode a [ Tree a ] | TLeaf a deriving Foldable
```

The [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) is defined on any `Foldable`, so we can then sum with:

```
Prelude> sum (TNode (-1) [TNode (-5)  [  TNode (-4) [ TLeaf 13, TLeaf 17] ,  TLeaf 30 ] ,TLeaf 10 ])
60
```

Comment: i am confused about the  DeriveFoldable extension, can the problem being solved without it?

Comment: @JohnTang: yes, the first section describes what the problem is, with the `...` left as exercise.

Comment: i have a question,is it sum(..) or sum[..],because when i type >sum (1,4) it gives  4 ,which is really confusing, but sum [1,4] works fine.

Comment: @JohnTang: that is because you work with a tuple, and you thus use the `Foldable` instance of a 2-tuple, but the `(...)` in the code should *generate* a list. If you however work with `[ x ]` you create a *singleton* list, a list containing one element. So you should simply look for an expression that generates a list.